# When to bind this keyword to an event handler in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, let's say I have a class named Search that is a simple input field with a submit button. Here's the code for that.

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {term: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({term: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <form className='input-group'>
                    <input className='form-control' 
                    placeholder='City' 
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={this.state.value}/>
                    <span className='input-group-btn'>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
        )
    }
}
```

So, I need to bind the `this` keyword to the event handler, `handleChange`,  inside the constructor of the class so that it has the correct reference to `this` inside the `handleChange` event handler.

However, if I change the code to the following

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {term: ''};

        //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

> Line comment above

```
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.setState({term: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <form className='input-group'>
                    <input className='form-control' 
                    placeholder='City' 
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
```

> Line change above

```
                    value={this.state.value}/>
                    <span className='input-group-btn'>
                        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, if I change the code to the above, I no longer need to do that because I am calling this.handleChange from inside of a callback. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) when you create the callback.

You don't need to bind arrow functions to this, because arrow functions "lexically binds the this value".

If you want, you can change your event handler functions into arrow functions, so that you don't need to bind them. You may need to add the babel plugin ['transform-class-properties'](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to transpile classes with arrow functions.

If you want to change `handleChange` into an arrow function, simply change

```
handleChange(e) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have to consider is what you are expecting`this` will evaluate to inside a method and this is something that is ***not*** just confined to callbacks.

In the the case of your `handleChange` method you are referring to `this.setState` where you are expecting `this` to be the body of your containing class where it is defined when you create a class extending from `React.Component`.

When a DOM on-event handler like `onClick` is invoked, the `this` keyword inside the handler is set to the DOM element on which it was invoked from. See: [Event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) and [this on in-line handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_in%E2%80%93line_event_handler).

As you can infer, there is no `setState` method on a DOM element, so in order to achieve the desired result, binding the this to the correct scope/context is necessary.

This can be achieved with .bind() or the `=>` ([arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), the latter of which does not define its own its own scope/context and uses the scope/context it is enclosed in.

Like I said previously the redefining of `this` is not just confined to DOM on-event callbacks. Another example is when you call the `.map()` method where you can define the context of `this` by passing in a context value as a second argument.

Comment: You don't need to `bind(this)` if you use arrow functions, who [lexically binds the this value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions). Their `this` value is always the same, no matter where they're called from.

Comment: Thanks @ArneHugo, I'm submitting the answer in partial posts whilst on the go with a patchy connection. Full answer up now.